# client.connected returns false when I am doing mqtt connection in React-Native.. why?

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mqtt

I am doing a client app using React Native and a Nodejs server on my laptop and I want to make them communicate through MQTT. The client MQTT which is the node is connecting successfully to mqtt://test.mosquitto.org while the client in react-native doesn't connect and client.connect returns false always.
I'm a beginner in React-Native and MQTT protocol.

I tried putting the connection part in componentDidMount() and it didn't work and I tried putting it in the onPress function of a button and it also didn't work.

```
var mqtt = require('@taoqf/react-native-mqtt');
var client = null;


handleActivate(e) {

    client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://test.mosquitto.org', { clientId: 'mqtt44e3f' });
             //this is the part that gives me false
    console.log('Client connection: ' + client.connected);
    client.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('connection: true');
    });
    var topic = 'carLocation';
    client.subscribe(topic); //single topic
    client.on('message', function(topic, message, packet) {
        console.log('message is ' + message);
        console.log('topic is ' + topic);
    });
}


render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <View style={styles.button}>
                    <Button title="Activate" color="#841584" onPress={this.handleActivate} />
                </View>
            </View>
        </View>
    );
}
```

Comment: Do you get `Client connection` log?

Comment: yes I get( Client connection: false )